# Using AngularFirestore Collection orderBy with snapShotChanges method

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have below code in an Angular application which is using AngularFire2.

TypeScript:

```
constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.booksCollectionRef = db.collection<Book>('books');

    this.books = this.booksCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
        return actions.map(action => {
            const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Book;
            const id = action.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
        });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let book of books | async">
        <h4 md-line>{{book.name}}</h4>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

This code retrieves and binds data as expected (removes items when collection updated), now I want to sort the collection by a given column. I tried to use firebase [orderBy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) clause, but I can not figure out how to use it with `snapShotChanges()` method.

Comment: Have you tried: `this.books = this.booksCollectionRef.orderBy('name','desc').snapshotChanges().map(actions =>`

Comment: @GalBracha that also does not work. `Property 'orderBy' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<Book>'`

Comment: Have you tried the default `sort()` function of TypeScript ? If not then please provide us with the structure of your `this.books`.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi, Not yet. That would be my last option.But I'm trying to get this done within 'snapshotChanges()' because I may need  to use some other functions in firestore collection, similarly.

Comment: I am not following, if you are using `.map` after your `snapshotChanges()` call, can't you simply follow that by a `.sort` call to sort your results ?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Yes I can, But say I want to use `where` clause instead of `orderBy`, then if I select all the records from firestore and filtering it using TypeScript methods would be inappropriate, I guess.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The following should work for your use case:

```
this.booksCollectionRef = db.collection<Book>('books', ref => ref.orderBy('order field'));
```

Take a look at the [documentation of AngularFirestore](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/0f6f2bf83c93a3a475bbfe4f7d37a6aa6fc1d03d/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#creating-a-query-with-primitivescalar-values) for further information on this topic.

Comment: But I can not find a way to use `ref.orderBy` method with `snapShotChanges` method, Can you please show me a sample code...

Comment: It should be working if you just replace the first line in your constructor with the one I posted. Check out the example app at the bottom of the page I linked, they use this approach in combination with valueChanges()

Comment: Did you change orderBy(‘order field‘) to the correct field of your books you want to order by?

Comment: I'm so sorry... I tried this again and it works.. Previous day I've missed something... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to help! ;)

Comment: I'm using timestamp as orderBy and its showing latest added at last. It should show first

Answer (score 11):

```js
this.announcementCollectionRef = afs.collection<Announcement>('announcements', ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
this.announcements = this.announcementCollectionRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as AnnouncementId;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
    });
});
```

Comment: life saver. This code worked for me w/ ionic, angular2fire, and firestore.

Comment: How is this supposed to work when you don't subscribe to the DocumentChangeAction observer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Angular Fire, but you can try using the Firebase Firestore libraries directly.

The following code works for me:

```
someCollectionRef
.orderBy('columnName')
.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
snapshot.docChanges.forEach(function (change) {
...doStuff
```

Comment: Do you know why it says to me "Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '(options?: SnapshotListenOptions) => DocumentChange[]'." please?